# iframe has scrollbars when display: inline-block is used

Tags: jquery, html, css, iframe

So I have a page with an iframe and, in that iframe, I have a div who's height is being set to the height of the window via jquery. This element is set to `display: inline-block` so that it's width is the width of the content contained within the div as opposed to filling the page completely.

The problem is...  when `display: inline-block` is used a scrollbar appears that doesn't appear when `display: block` is used.

The website:

http://www.frostjedi.com/terra/scripts/demo/two-scrollbars.html

The code:

```
<body style="margin: 0; padding: 0">
  <div style="width: 5000px; height: 10px; background: black"></div>
  <iframe src="two-scrollbars-iframe.html" style="border: 0; width: 100%; height: 100%"></iframe>
</body>
```

two-scrollbars-iframe.html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN"
  "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="en">
<head>

<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min.js"></script>

<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(".screen").height($(window).height());
});
</script>

</head>

<body style="margin: 0">
<div style="width: 300px; background: green; display: inline-block" class="screen"></div>
</body>
```

Here it is with `display: block`:

http://www.frostjedi.com/terra/scripts/demo/two-scrollbars-2.html

I've also noticed that even with `display: inline-block` the iframe's scrollbar goes away if I remove the 5000px wide div. Unfortunately, I can't do that in the final application I'm trying to write because I don't have any control over the "outer" frame.

Any ideas?

Comment: adding anything in screen div remove the second scrollbar, i don't know why...

Answer (score 0):

Try absolute positioning.

```
.screen
{
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    bottom: 0;
}
```

The width will not stretch to fill the container as would a normal block element, and it doesn't require JavaScript or jQuery.